# Como imprimir informacion de una llave foranea en laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente problema en laravel. Quiero mostrar mediante un modal información de una *orden de servicio*, pero mando a llamar una llave foranea que se llama `cliente` y requiero imprimir el nombre del `cliente` y su direccion pero me marca este error:

> Attempt to read property "nombre" on string

Cabe destacar que mi llave foránea ya está relacionada en el modelo que se llama orden

En el modelo `Orden`

```php
public function cliente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cliente::class, 'cliente', 'cliente'); // 'cliente' es el nombre de la llave foránea en la tabla de órdenes 
}
```

Mis tablas son las siguientes tengo una tabla que se llama `ordenes` y mi `id` orden. Sobre el controlador `ordencontroller` estoy trabajando y en mi vista de ordenes, cuando le doy clik al icono de *ver*, quiero que se abra el modal y que me muestre la informacion de esa orden de servicio con los datos del cliente, pero no lo he podido lograr, ¿alguna sugerencia?.

Comment: como llamas al modelo? con get(), all() o first() ????

Comment: Te sugiero leer en la documentación de laravel como definir una relación [BelongsTo (one to many inverse)](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse), y como cargar una relación en el resultado de la consulta [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading). Para ayudarte, necesitaríamos saber los nombres de la llave foranea de Orden y de la llave primaria de Cliente. También sería útil que muestres como haces la consulta a la BD con el modelo Orden